# Strange background on Huawei Watch, ok in Wear OS emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, wearables

I'm running DataLayer example from Android Studio 3.4.2
The example demonstrates how to send an image from phone to wearable. It works but on the wearable (Huawei Watch with: Android Wear 2.26.0, Google Play Services 17.7.85 and Android OS 7.1.1) there is an annoying semi-transparent background distorting the image. The background is like a watch face (lines around the edge and a dot in the middle.) When running exactly the same example on Wear Os emulator the image (400x400pixels) is perfect, without the strange background. Does anyone know why this happens on the watch?

I also tried Free Web Explorer from Google Play store. It also shows up with the same semi-transparent background.

Link to photo showing Emulator and Huawei Watch side by side:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nmifz5cnmuo1q_Q9A56PZH4qc0wNxwZ-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Guess this question really came to the wrong place. Found out it has nothing to do with software. The problem is screen burn in. I did not know that modern screen technologies (OLED in this case) suffers so much by displaying the same image (watch face in this case) for a long time. I thought it was a problem only with older displays. Like CRT displays which were used as consoles back in the days..